# CSS nth-child doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to change the color only the third one but for some reason css nth-of-type doesn't work...

```css
    ul li a:nth-of-type(3){
        color: #111111;
    }
```

```html
 <ul>
        <li class="nav_menu"><a id="currentlink" href="#">HOME PAGE</a></li>
        <li class="nav_menu"><a href="homework/homework2/index.html">II</a></li>
        <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">III</a></li>
        <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">IV</a></li>
        <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">V</a></li>
        <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">VI</a></li>
        <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">VII</a></li>
        <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">VIII</a></li>
        <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">IX</a></li>
        <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">X</a></li>
    </ul>
```

How do I fix this? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be:

```
ul li:nth-of-type(3) a {
    color: #111111;
}
```

You want the `a` tag inside the third `li`.

Answer (score 2):

list of `<li>` and than `a`

```
ul li:nth-of-type(3) a{
    color: #111111;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d8oz6qbu/

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting the **a** tag in your css, while you need to select the third list item. not the third **a** tag

try

```
ul li:nth-child(3) {
    color: #111111;
}
```

or

```
ul li:nth-child(3) a {
  color: #111111;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

nth-of-type targets the nth child of the specified elements parent (of the same type).

So your css:

```
ul li a:nth-of-type(3){
    color: #111111;
}
```

was targeting the third child of your `li` which doesn't exist as your `li` has a single child `a`

what you want is:

```
ul li:nth-of-type(3) a{
    color: #111111;
}
```

which targets the 3rd child of `ul` which is a `li`, then change the color of any `a` tags that follow.

Snippet:

```css
ul li:nth-of-type(3) a{
    color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a id="currentlink" href="#">HOME PAGE</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="homework/homework2/index.html">II</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">III</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">IV</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">V</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">VI</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">VII</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">VIII</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">IX</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">X</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code,

```
<ul>

    <li class="nav_menu"><a id="currentlink" href="#">HOME PAGE</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="homework/homework2/index.html">II</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">III</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">IV</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">V</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">VI</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">VII</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">VIII</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">IX</a></li>
    <li class="nav_menu"><a href="#">X</a></li>
</ul>
<style>
ul li:nth-child(3) a{
    color: #111111;
}
</style>
```